# Centering caption in figure environment with a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, captions

I'm trying to center a tikzpicture and a caption inside the figure environment, but when I compile something is off. It seems as if the caption and the tikzpicture are centering with respect to diferent referenes. I'm using Overleaf.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}[ ymin=0, xlabel = variáveis aleatórias, ylabel = frequência]

\addplot [
    domain=0:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red]
    {exp(-x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please replace `e^-x` by `exp(-x)`.

Comment: The whole figure is centered with the caption, including the axis, the legend and so on. This is why the caption is not centered with the `x` legend.

Answer (score 3):

As Sigur points out, the caption is centered w.r.t. the full tikzpicture, not just the plot, but the plot with labels. If you *really* don't want this, you might mess around with the bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\begin{axis}[ ymin=0, xlabel = variáveis aleatórias, ylabel = frequência]

\addplot [
    domain=0:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red]
    {exp(-x)};
\end{axis}
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\path[use as bounding box] ([yshift=-8mm]current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other options include shifting the caption to the left, or, what might be more elegant, to add the same space to the bounding box on the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,
             xlabel=variáveis aleatórias,
             ylabel=frequência,
             ylabel style={alias=ylab}]

\addplot [
    domain=0:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red]
    {exp(-x)};
\end{axis}
\path let \p1=($(current axis.west)-(ylab.north)$) 
  in (current axis.east) -- ++(\x1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This saves you from having to add an `yshift` by hand.

Comment: Perfect solution. I didn't know about this bb env.

Comment: @Sigur I added a second, less harmful solution. Even though I do not expect that interrupting the bounding box is worrisome in *this* case, this is something which should generally be avoided, if possible.

Comment: I liked both. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant of Marmot's solution using the calc tikzlibrary and the `[name=...]` option for axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, xlabel = variáveis aleatórias, ylabel = frequência,
    name=border]
\addplot [
    domain=0:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red]
    {exp(-x)};
\end{axis}
% center tikzpicture relative to axis (border)
\path ($(border.center)!-1!(current bounding box.west)$);
\draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% demo only
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

---

This solution places the caption inside the tikzpicture, within the axis border (horizontally).  This makes the tikzpicture smaller but provides much less space for the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, xlabel = variáveis aleatórias, ylabel = frequência,
    name=border]
\addplot [
    domain=0:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red]
    {exp(-x)};
\end{axis}
% center tikzpicture relative to axis (border)
\pgfextractx{\tempwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{border}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{border}{east}}}%
\node[below] at (border.south |- current bounding box.south) {\begin{minipage}{\tempwidth}
    \caption{Some figure}
\end{minipage}};
\draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% demo only
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```