# Subcaptions not centered for pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, subcaption

This is my first time working with side-by-side pgfplots, so I am a little out of my zone of comfort. However, I noticed that my subcaptions for each panel is not centered around the figure, as in:

[image]

For panel (a), it seems like it's centered - but I would prefer a centering like the x-labels, where they are centered around what's visible on the figure - and not any whitespacing (if that makes sense). However, for panel (b), I cannot get the subcaption to be centered, even though I have used the same code.

My code is the following:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\documentclass[]{bachelor}
\LoadClass[a4paper]{report}    
\begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \centering
            \pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks=false}
            \caption{Peer rank vs. \\ Average Annual Search Fraction}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=10cm,
            ylabel={Peer Rank},
            xlabel={Average Annual Search Fraction},
            xmin=0,
            xmax=4,
            ymin=-5,
            ymax=100,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
            ]

            \addplot table [x=c, y=b, col sep=comma] {Datafiles/rankvsasf1.csv};

            \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{subfigure}
        \hfill

    \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{Log Peer Rank vs. \\ Log average Annual Search Fractions}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=10cm,
            ylabel={Log Peer Rank},
            xlabel={Log Average Annual Search Fraction},
            xmin=-6,
            xmax=-2,
            ymin=-0,
            ymax=4,
            xtick={-6,-5,-4,-3,-2},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            xtick style={draw=none},
        ]

            \addplot table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {Datafiles/loglog.csv};

            ]

      \draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] (rel axis cs:0.45,0.9) node[right,draw,align=left] {y=-6.38-1.63x\\ $R^2$=99.7\%};


            \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please, can you edit your MWE: missing `\documentclass`. Thank you.

Comment: The first one seems to be centered w.r.t. to the full `tikzpicture` and as for the second one, probably the axis is too wide to fit.

Comment: Are there any warnings about overfull boxes?

Comment: I added the documentclass. 

There are no warnings about overfull boxes, even adjusting the width does not help.

Comment: Your code is far from compilable. Apart from the fact that `bachelor` does not seem to be a standard class, there are no `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. When one fixes this, one can still not compile because we do not have your data. Please provide us with a compilable code using only classes that are on the standard installations, or give us links to the `bachelor` class.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453093/centering-caption-in-figure-environment-with-a-tikzpicture.  Of course, there he centered the tikzpicture relative to the axis (much easier).

Answer (score 1):

This solution puts the caption inside a node in the tikzpicture, using only the width of the axis.

I tried centering the tikzpicture relative to the axis, but it wasted too much space on the right.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}    
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}% default not wide enough
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering, singlelinecheck=false}

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]% !h is just embarrassing.
        \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \centering
            \pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks=false}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=10cm,
            ylabel={Peer Rank},
            xlabel={Average Annual Search Fraction},
            xmin=0,
            xmax=4,
            ymin=-5,
            ymax=100,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
            name=border
            ]
            %\addplot table [x=c, y=b, col sep=comma] {Datafiles/rankvsasf1.csv};% file not found
            \end{axis}
        %place caption above axis
            \pgfextractx{\tempwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{border}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{border}{east}}}%
            \node[above] at (border.north) {\begin{minipage}{\tempwidth}
              \caption{Peer rank vs. \\ Average Annual Search Fraction}
            \end{minipage}};
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \centering

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=10cm,
            ylabel={Log Peer Rank},
            xlabel={Log Average Annual Search Fraction},
            xmin=-6,
            xmax=-2,
            ymin=-0,
            ymax=4,
            xtick={-6,-5,-4,-3,-2},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            xtick style={draw=none},
            name=border
        ]
            %\addplot table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {Datafiles/loglog.csv};% file not found
            ]
      \draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] (rel axis cs:0.45,0.9) node[right,draw,align=left] {y=-6.38-1.63x\\ $R^2$=99.7\%};
            \end{axis}
        %place caption above axis
            \pgfextractx{\tempwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{border}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{border}{east}}}%
            \node[above] at (border.north) {\begin{minipage}{\tempwidth}
              \caption{Log Peer Rank vs. \\ Log average Annual Search Fractions}
            \end{minipage}};
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of John's answer. Instead of measuring the width of the axis, you can use `text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}`, and instead of a separate node, I add the caption in the `title` of the `axis`.

`text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}` actually makes the title node a bit wider than the axis itself, because twice the `inner sep` of the node comes in addition, and because the width of the axis box is 45pt less than the defined width when `scale only axis` is not included.

I also show a different method for making the general layout, using a `groupplot` instead of two `subfigure` environments. It shortens the code a bit. Note I used `\subcaption` instead of `\caption` in the titles.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}    
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}% default not wide enough
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} % <-- added
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering, singlelinecheck=false}

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \centering
            \pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks=false}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=10cm,
            ylabel={Peer Rank},
            xlabel={Average Annual Search Fraction},
            xmin=0,
            xmax=4,
            ymin=-5,
            ymax=100,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
            title style={text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}},% this is actually a bit wider than the axis
            title=\caption{Peer rank vs. \\ Average Annual Search Fraction}
            ]
            %\addplot table [x=c, y=b, col sep=comma] {Datafiles/rankvsasf1.csv};% file not found
            \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \centering

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=10cm,
            ylabel={Log Peer Rank},
            xlabel={Log Average Annual Search Fraction},
            xmin=-6,
            xmax=-2,
            ymin=-0,
            ymax=4,
            xtick={-6,-5,-4,-3,-2},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            xtick style={draw=none},
            title style={text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}},
            title=\caption{Log Peer Rank vs. \\ Log average Annual Search Fractions}
        ]
            %\addplot table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {Datafiles/loglog.csv};% file not found
            ]
      \draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] (rel axis cs:0.45,0.9) node[right,draw,align=left] {$y=-6.38-1.63x$\\ $R^2=99.7\%$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

     \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
       group style={
         group size={2 by 1},
         horizontal sep=2cm
       },  
       width=7cm,height=10cm,
       axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
       xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
       xtick style={draw=none},
       title style={text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}, % this is actually a bit wider than the axis
       ]

       \nextgroupplot[
            ylabel={Peer Rank},
            xlabel={Average Annual Search Fraction},
            xmin=0,
            xmax=4,
            ymin=-5,
            ymax=100,
            scaled x ticks=false,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill]{\tick}\%},
            title=\subcaption{Peer rank vs. \\ Average Annual Search Fraction}
            ]

            %\addplot table [x=c, y=b, col sep=comma] {Datafiles/rankvsasf1.csv};% file not found

       \nextgroupplot[
            ylabel={Log Peer Rank},
            xlabel={Log Average Annual Search Fraction},
            xmin=-6,
            xmax=-2,
            ymin=-0,
            ymax=4,
            xtick={-6,-5,-4,-3,-2},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            title=\subcaption{Log Peer Rank vs. \\ Log average Annual Search Fractions}
        ]
            %\addplot table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {Datafiles/loglog.csv};% file not found
            ]
      \draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] (rel axis cs:0.45,0.9) node[right,draw,align=left] {$y=-6.38-1.63x$\\ $R^2=99.7\%$};
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}



\end{figure}
\end{document}
```